# Alter Ego very disgusting

Tags: discussion

By popular demand and to be exact;

There is an alter ego [Adolf Eichmann](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/40609/adolf-eichmann) that is very disgusting and offensive.

Is there a decent way to clean up such violations?

I would like to expunge such bad jokes from SE.

PS

and a question [Arithmetic Progression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116159/arithmetic-progression) ... is a question.

Comment: I would agree that using the name of a notorious war criminal as a pseudonym is in very poor taste.

Comment: I have temporarily changed the name of the user in question, and sent him a message. Let's hope he listens.

Comment: @J.M., i like your sense of humor, your work as a Moderator and your contribution to SE. Thank you for support.

Comment: @J.M. Not a bad choice, but I would have gone with Eselmann.

Comment: "Is there a decent way to clean up such violations?" -- Let us implement a censorship system that objectively quantifies the offensiveness of MSE posts and removes those with high enough scores (or adherence to a certain distribution of sentiment measures). We can use some of the sentiment analysis tools already provided in Mathematica...

Comment: This reminds me of the rather shocking story on [NPR](http://www.npr.org/2012/12/23/167911062/hitlers-hot-in-india). It's clearly necessary to speak out when such things happen, even (or especially) when the person in question doesn't realize what they're actually doing. There was a similar issue related to the "Lena" test image - I think some people felt offended by its history and pointed it out.

Comment: I should add that I'm not implying that the Lena image is nearly as offensive as using Nazi references. Unfortunately I can't find the post where this discussion happened - but I believe it was resolved easily by changing the image used in the post.

Comment: About Lena see here [Should we discourage the use of Lenna?](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/should-we-discourage-the-use-of-lenna/1601#1601)

Comment: BTW, Lena, I like Lena.

Comment: Lena at least had the choice and the possibility to deal with something else. Not every prostitute or drug addict has this choice. Absolutely no war victim had this freedom of choice. This is a place of free speech. We are here to learn and to grow mental and humanely. To exploit someone mentally, physically or economically, to despise someone because of gender, nationality, ethnic origin or faith is not civilized nor matured. It is barbarous. But anyone can think and talk and deal about un- / fairness how He likes.

Comment: The problem is, who and where do you set the limit (between acceptable and not acceptable)? Meanwhile the aforementionned user has 142 profile views for 1 question...